# How do I load an image from HTML to Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I have an HTML page that lets you upload a picture and displays it (very simple). But how do I send that particular loaded image into my flask app so that I could, say, perform some image processing on it using python's openCV or PIL packages?

Comment: There is something called request.files check it out here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Disclaimer

I've done similar thing recently, It may not be a 100% solution for you, but using parts of this code will propably solve all of your problems.

## Flask Code

This part gets all files uploaded from browser and saves them with their respected extensions.

```
if request.method=="PUT":
        for f in request.files.getlist("Files"): #<---- note 1
            f.save(os.path.join(Path_To_Folder, f.filename)) 
        return jsonify({"result": "res"}), 200 #status code is only thing important here
```

## HTML

This just allows you to select file(s) from your device

```
<input type="file" id="file_loader" multiple/>
```

## JavaScript

This code

```
const file_loader = document.getElementById("file_loader");

file_loader.onchange = async function(e){   
    alert("Upload started")
    let sending = new FormData(); //creates form data object

//this for loop adds all files you selected to a form object
    for (let i = 0; i < file_loader.files.length; i++) {        
        sending.append("Files", file_loader.files[i]);   //<---- note 1 
    }

//this part just sends all the files to server
    const podaci = await fetch(url_filesistem, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: sending,        
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((pod) => {return pod;}); 
       
//removing all selected files from an input, so every time you want to select files
//its just those files, not ones previously selected
    while (file_loader.length > 0) {
        file_loader.pop();
    } 
    alert("Finnished uploading")    
}
```

## Note 1

String "Files" mentioned in both lines needs to be the same in order for this method to work.

## Advice

First save all the files on the server and then do the processing. I don't know what "f" object from for loop in python contains, therefore I don't know whether you can process them immediately.

*Feel free to ask me anything regarding my code!*

**Best regards!**